# SQL Query Optimisation/tidying up a problematic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone can just take a look at my query below please.  I am having some CPU issues on a site I have running that is slowing the site down at peak times.

When users register the system selects the Easting and Northing values from a Postcode table with 1.8million rows, I have an index set up on this table and believe it is running as well as I possible but then I also have another query that is showing to be quite a high cost (28% in some sections) when I am looking at it in the execution plan.

The query below selects Account Details, an Average of a users Star Rating and also uses a function that calculates the mileage between the user who is logged in and all results in order to display the nearest first.

Can you see anything glaringly wrong with the way I've put this together, my SQL is ok but limited so would appreciate any help as it's a long running issue.

```
SELECT  tblAccounts.accountID ,
        tblAccounts.city ,
        tblAccounts.emailAddress ,
        tblAccounts.paypalEmailAddress ,
        tblAccounts.skypeUsername ,
        tblAccounts.EA ,
        tblAccounts.postcode ,
        [onlineBootyUser].[fn_radialDistance](tblAccounts.EA, tblAccounts.NO,
                                              @EA, @NO) AS miles ,
        tblOrders.tableclothVisible ,
        ( SELECT    AVG(starRating) AS averageRating
          FROM      onlinebootyUser.tblStarRating
          WHERE     ( accountID = onlinebootyUser.tblOrders.accountID )
        ) AS starRating
FROM    tblOrders
        INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID = tblAccounts.accountID
WHERE   ( tblAccounts.valid = 1 )
        AND ( ( tblOrders.orderStatus = 'Completed' )
              OR ( tblOrders.orderStatus = 'Pending' )
            )
        AND tblOrders.bootsaleDate = @bootsaleDate
        AND tblOrders.itemsAllowed > 0
        AND ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
              FROM      tblItems
              WHERE     tblItems.accountID = tblAccounts.accountID
                        AND tblItems.bootsaleDate = @bootSaleDate
            ) > 0
ORDER BY miles ASC
```

The function `fn_radialDistance` is as follows:

```
declare @d float;

        set @d = power(square(@east1-@east2)+square(@north1-@north2),0.5E)/1609.0E

        return @d
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: It might be worth moving the subqueries into 2 seperate CROSS APPLY's.  The count(*) would be quite heavy and has to compare it for every row in the source table.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan?  Seeing that would help a lot.

Comment: Not too sure what part of the plan you are wishing to see, this is the overall view...

http://imageshack.com/a/img541/4745/24kp.png

Comment: can you add aliases to your tables to help determine what columns come from what tables?

Comment: There's a better formatted code below with all aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query formatted so I can read it:

```
SELECT a.accountID, a.city, a.emailAddress, a.paypalEmailAddress, a.skypeUsername, a.EA,
       a.postcode,
       [onlineBootyUser].[fn_radialDistance](tblAccounts.EA, a.NO, @EA, @NO) AS miles,
       o.tableclothVisible,
       (SELECT AVG(starRating) AS averageRating
        FROM onlinebootyUser.tblStarRating sr
        WHERE sr.accountID = o.accountID
       ) AS starRating
FROM tblOrders o INNER JOIN
     tblAccounts a
     ON o.accountID = a.accountID
WHERE (a.valid = 1) AND (o.orderStatus in ('Completed', 'Pending')) AND
      o.bootsaleDate = @bootsaleDate AND o.itemsAllowed > 0 AND
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM tblItems i
       WHERE i.accountID = a.accountID AND i.bootsaleDate = @bootSaleDate
      ) > 0
ORDER BY miles ASC
```

The question that arises is what indexes you have.  The following indexes should help:

```
tblItems(accountID, bootsaleDate);
tblStarRating(accountID, starRating);
```

You can make the subquery in the `where` more efficient by replacing it with `exists`:

```
exists (select 1
        from tblItems i
        where i.accountID = a.accountID and i.bootsaleDate = @bootSaleDate
      )
```

This is probably a minor improvement, unless the number of matches is quite high.

Beyond that, you would did to provide an execution plan.  It is quite likely that the function call is hurting performance.

Comment: I just have accountID on tblItems and accountID, orderDate on tblOrders.

These were suggested by the Execution Plan

Comment: The indexes I mention are for the subqueries.  The ones you have seem reasonable, although I would be inclined to have `tblOrders(bootSaleDate, OrderStatus, AccountId)`.